# RESTful query parameter at GET method

Tags: rest, http

If I have a GET restful api use for query user info by user name. I don't want to return all column.
My response column is decide to client.

Example.
My user have many column.(userName, sex, phone, address, age)
When my client only want to query the user phone and age by user name.
My restful api is like: `/rest/user?userName=Bob&resultColumn={"column":["phone","age"]}`

Is there a better way to represent the resultColumn parameter?
Maybe like **resultColumn=phone,age** , **resultColumn=phone;age** or other format?

Comment: arent facebook developed graphQL for this problems?

Comment: Do you develop the api, and want to make an endpoint that is easier to use? Why not put everything into a json object? I personally find it easier to manage than queries, when it gets more complex. Though its use-case deviates a bit from using a query.